# npm publish: verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: npm, http-status-code-400, npm-publish

I use `npm publish` return the error 400 Bad Request,
I tried the method with next steps:

- `delete node_modules`
- `npm cache clean -f`
- `npm install`
- `npm audit`

But its not working. If you have the same trouble or solution method，please tell me，thanks！

My env is `windows10: v18363.1198` `node: v14.15.1` `npm: v6.14.9`

> ```
> http fetch PUT 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/byte-download 1400ms
> verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/byte-download - Bad Request
> verbose stack     at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:117:15
> verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> verbose statusCode 400
> ```

Comment: I fund the reason, although my package name is not duplicate in npm, my package name contains `download` it seems that irregular, so I changed the name to `byte-to-file` and its work.

Comment: I love you so much, I would have never figured that out on my own, god knows why npm chooses to just give you a cryptic error

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not able to find any documentation on this. But my package also contained the word "download" and this is apparently not allowed.